# How to apply Less css in Genesis Framework

Tags: css, frameworks, less, lesscss-resources

Can anyone have experienced with Less CSS style applied in Genesis Framework with Bones Child Theme? 
How can I get start on it?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

For any WordPress theme in general. First remove the theme stylesheets with the [wp_dequeue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) function. Don't delete these files (for most themes this will the style.css and probably some other theme stylesheets) don't delete these files. Notice that the Genesis Framework en- and dequeue the stylesheet with actions. to remove them use `remove_action( 'genesis_meta', 'genesis_load_stylesheet' );` (source: http://www.chriswiegman.com/2013/06/remove-the-default-style-css-in-wordpress-with-genesis/)

Than create a index.less files which should contain something like that shown below:

```
@import (less) "style.css"; // correct path to you original /wp_content/themes/{your_theme}/style.css
@import (less) "otherthemefile.css" // correct path to you original /wp_content/themes/{your_theme}/otherthemefile.css
/* custom less code here */
```

Finally compile the `index.less` file into something like `main.css`. Upload the `main.css` to your theme's directory and use [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to load it in your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your help!